# Dock's badge count doesn't work properly for chromium

Tags: 20.04, snap, chromium, ubuntu-dock, dock

**Background**

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on several different machines (Dell XPS13 laptop, two desktops) and in all of them, I experience the same problem.

**Problem description**

I've installed chromium from snap and since I use it quite often, I added it to the dock's favorites (using the `Add to Favorites` button). More often than not, when I open a chromium window by pressing on the chromium icon in the dock, the window opens (and runs) properly, but the badge count associated with chromium in the dock remains on zero, that is, it does not indicate the existence of the open window (with a little orange dot appearing to the left of the chromium icon).

To illustrate this problem, here is a screenshot of the dock when one firefox and one chromium windows are open:

[image: Screenshot of the dock. No orange dot next to the chromium icon]

You can clearly see that there is an orange dot next to the firefox icon, indicating that there is one firefox window open (badge count = 1) and the lack of such an orange dot next to the chromium icon (badge count = 0).

Some additional info:

- The problem doesn't always occur. I can't identify any pattern as to when would it happen.
- When pressing the `Super` button to show the existing open windows, the chromium window does appear.
- If I press the chromium icon in the dock again, it will open a new chromium window that usually does trigger the appearance of an orange dot next to the chromium icon (so the badge count shows 1, whereas the number of open chromium windows is actually 2).
- This problem seems to occur only with chromium. This may be related to sanp though as chromium is the only frequently used application that I installed through snap (most of my applications are installed through apt).

Any ideas?

Comment: I have seen this with other applications so I suspect it's an interaction between snapd and the desktop environment rather than chromium itself.